# How to clear all running timeouts before setting a new timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the mic icon **two times simultaneously** it comes back to inactive state but the timeout function still takes place.

**Below are my console values :**

```
true
false
false
```

**Instead of:**

```
true
false
```

[image]

How to prevent this from happening.

```
// Start listening on click.
var active= false;
var $mic = $("#mic-container");
$mic.click(function(event){
    //event.preventDefault();
    // if we're recording when the button is clicked
    if(active) {
        $mic.removeClass("active pulse");
        active=false; console.log(active);
        annyang.abort();                    
    // if we're not recording when the button is clicked
    } else {
        annyang.start({ autoRestart: false, continuous: false });                       // start listening
        active = true;                   console.log(active);   // set recording var to true
        $mic.addClass('active pulse');          // turn on active class
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $mic.removeClass("active pulse");      
            active=false;  console.log(active);
            annyang.abort();                
        }, 8000);
    }
});

annyang.addCallback('resultNoMatch', function () {
    $('.myErrorText').html('Try saying a valid command. See <a href="help.html" data-ajax="false">help</a> section for a list of valid commands!');
    $mic.addClass("result-no-match");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $mic.removeClass("active pulse result-no-match");
        active=false;  console.log(active);
        annyang.abort();
    }, 500);
});

annyang.addCallback('resultMatch', function () {
    $('.myErrorText').text('');
    $mic.addClass("result-match");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $mic.removeClass("active pulse result-match");
        active=false;  console.log(active);
        annyang.abort();
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i had the same kind of problem. Try this

```
// Start listening on click.       
    var timeoutHandle;
    var active= false;
    var $mic = $("#mic-container");
    $mic.click(function(event){
            //event.preventDefault();
            if(active)
                annyang.abort();
            else 
                annyang.start({ autoRestart: false, continuous: false});                        

    });

    annyang.addCallback('start', function () {
        active = true;              console.log(active);     
        $mic.addClass('active pulse');  
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(annyang.abort, 5000);

    });

    annyang.addCallback('end', function () {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {$mic.removeClass("active pulse result-match result-no-match");}, 200);
        active=false; console.log(active);
    });

    annyang.addCallback('resultNoMatch', function () {
        $mic.addClass("result-no-match");
        $('.myErrorText').html('Try saying a valid command. See <a href="help.html" data-ajax="false">help</a> section for a list of valid commands!');
    });

    annyang.addCallback('resultMatch', function () {
        $('.myErrorText').text('');
        $mic.addClass("result-match");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that timeouts are being started while those from previous clicks are still counting.

You're going to have to keep track of the active timeouts, and cancel them if they're running while the user clicks again.

This is possible because [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) returns an identifier you can pass to [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) to, as the function name suggests, cancel the timeout.

For example:

```
var resultMatchTimeout; // Variable to store a reference to a timeout in.
annyang.addCallback('resultMatch', function () {
    $('.myErrorText').text('');
    $mic.addClass("result-match");

    if(resultMatchTimeout){ // If a timeout is running, cancel it.
        clearTimeout(resultMatchTimeout);
        resultMatchTimeout = null;
    }

    resultMatchTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ // Save a reference to the current timeout.
        $mic.removeClass("active pulse result-match");
        active=false;  console.log(active);
        annyang.abort();
    }, 500);
});
```

You're going to have to do this for your other `setTimeout` calls too, obviously.
Just make sure to use different variables for each of the timeouts, otherwise, you 'll be cancelling the wrong timout.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the timeout to a variable and then just call the clearTimeout() method when you want to kill the timer. For example:

```
var resultMatchTimer = null;

// stops the timer
if(resultMatchTimer) {
    clearTimeout(resultMatchTimer);
    resultMatchTimer = null;
}

// starts the timer
resultMatchTimer = setTimeout(..., ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the result (handle) of setTimeout in a var and call clearTimeout on that handle.

```
var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(timeoutHandle); // this will clear the timeout.
```

With the correct scoping, you can call clearTimeout from all your clicks, and decide you need 3 handles to clear them individually or just use one form all setTimeouts and just clear it. When een new setTimeout is called your handle will be overwritten so make sure your clear the other timeout before that.

Comment: You can't just clear all timeouts, then you'd be left with stray classes on the `$mic`

Comment: No probably you'll need 3 different timeout handles... And when clearing them clean up the classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to consider: set the active/not-active state based on the actual voice recognition engine state and not based on user clicks. 
Check annyang.isListening()

Answer (score -1):

Every `setTimeout()` returns a unique Id which could be used to clear the timeout using `clearTimeout`.

I can see that you have multiple timers running, so what you could do is store all the ids returned each time from `setTimeout` method in a array and use the same array to clear all the `timers` in a loop.

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

JS CODE:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
   myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

Note: This is just a generic solution, which can be a base for final/actual solution

Comment: You can't just clear all timeouts, then you'd be left with stray classes on the `$mic`

Comment: @Cerbrus : can you explain briefly how that is possible ?

Comment: What do you mean with _"that"_? Also, don't add noise like _"happy Coding :)"_ to your answer. It adds no value.

Comment: Its not a noise, its a "Positive gesture". I wanted to know how would my solution  create stray classes  ?

Comment: It would create stray classes by cancelling timers that were meant to remove classes, added from a click. [It _is_ noise.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: regarding the stray classes,i beleive my solution is just a generic solution for the OP's question. this could be used to fix the actual problem posted here.  "NOISE" I wont agree with it, besides if you observe  the complete post,you will realise that there is no final conclusion to this topic, this is & will be a continuous discussion. 
FYI i like adding taglines, so please dont edit my posts. there are better edits required on SO.

Comment: @dreamweiver: if this is going to lead to a continuous discussion, then the question should be closed as too broad. We are aiming to create a *reusable repository of programming knowledge* here, not social interactions, so yes, we do remove noise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I really dont understand how much of a difference does it make with just 2 words(Nice Quote), I always feel good when adding tagline like this. *We live in a community were things need not be formal always*,besides none of these are offensive or offtopic .I strongly disagree with this.

Comment: @dreamweiver: then perhaps this isn't the site for you? Again, we aim to produce quality content that isn't *just* aimed at the person that typed in the question. The majority of the audience that views questions and answers are people coming in from search engines looking for a quick answer to their problem, not for a social connection.

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree with the _"this will be a continuous discussion"_ sentiment. My answer provides a working solution for the OP's problem, as described in his question.